# How to pivot if a column has null

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
source Type
a       null  
a       aa 
a       bb 
a       cc

source null aa bb cc
a.       1.  1 1 1
```

How to stop pivoting.a column which contains null

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: is below solution is working ??

Answer (score 0):

Filter the `null` values before `pivot`

Check below code.

```
scala> df.show(false)
+------+----+
|source|type|
+------+----+
|a     |null|
|a     |aa  |
|a     |bb  |
|a     |cc  |
+------+----+

scala> df
         .filter($"type".isNotNull)
         .groupBy($"source")
         .pivot($"type")
         .agg(count($"type"))
         .show(false)

+------+---+---+---+
|source|aa |bb |cc |
+------+---+---+---+
|a     |1  |1  |1  |
+------+---+---+---+
```